# Is password input sanitization required?

Tags: asp.net, security, input, passwords, sanitization

I'm trying to sanitize any data that's inputted by making sure the data is valid for a particular field (e.g. a name can't contain special characters/numbers etc..) However, I'm not sure what to do when it comes to a password field. Would I even need to bother with any sanitization as the password is simply hashed? If the user was to inject anything malicious via the password textbox, should I bother checking for anything suspicious? AFAIK, some users may (should!) have special characters such as '< >', which would normally trigger a potential attack alert. Should I just leave the password field unsanitized? Limiting input for passwords is a last resort for me, as I feel users should use all sorts of characters in their passwords.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for thinking about this and doing the Right Thing (tm).  I am so tired of websites that limit you to a specific character set or to only 10 characters or less.  And yes, I'm talking about the moron's building banking sites.

Comment: lol, I know what you mean. I'm still yet to see a valid reason to ever handicap a user's password.

Comment: It might be worth disallowing (though probably not stripping) some characters. For instance control characters, although some people used to put tab characters in UNIX passwords (I believe).

Comment: I think this would've been the best approach to take had the hashing not alleviated any dangerous code. As the original password isn't stored anywhere, the salted hash should be fine.

Comment: @XSL Agreed! The password should be hashed as soon as possible. If there is an attack on some website via code injected in the password, this website is passing around raw passwords for too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you are hashing it in your application, you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using ASP.NET membership controls to do all this, so hopefully I won't have to do any manual password changes. Therefore, only the hash will ever be stored, which I guess means that there's no threat.

Comment: In PHP\MySQL case, why is there a need to sanitize $pwd if it is hashed?

Comment: @Ubeogesh $pwd is not hashed.  The PASSWORD() function in MySQL hashes it for you.  That said, I wouldn't recommend using MySQL's PASSWORD function as there are better alternatives for password hashing available.

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about SQL Injection attacks, you should start using parametrized queries to interact with your database. As it's a business rule to determine what's valid characters to password, I wouldnt strip anything while my customer don't say so.

All other input should be sanitized, as they could also be displayed on your page output and could lead to XSS attacks.

Comment: Hi. I'm using the ASP.NET controls to allow users to register and change passwords, so I believe the queries are automatically parameterized. I'm manually sanitizing the other inputs before the UserCreated event, but the password input may get encoded thus changing the actual password. (e.g. < becomes &lt).

Comment: bottom line is: its doesnt matter, as it always will replace < by &lt;

Comment: That's a fair point and as long as I'm working on the project, that's fine. I'm just thinking in the long run, if the project changes hands, other developers may start interacting directly with the passwords and not encoding them in the same method which could cause some confusion. Although this is highly unlikely, I like to err on the side of caution.