# How to protect a password field from malicious input?

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, passwords, xss

I'm currently applying input validation to my apps input fields for security reasons. Eliminating special characters or applying a regular expression does the job for most fields but I'm stumped on the password as legitimate passwords may well contain special characters.

How can I protect this field from malicious attacks without invalidating legitimate passwords? 
*Note: I have no control over the rules the actual passwords follow.*

What I currently have in place below disallows any non-alphanumeric characters but most good passwords will contain special characters.

```
NSString *pattern = @"^(?:\\n|\\w)+$";
```

Comment: Malicious attacks from whom? Please provide a scenario.

Comment: Any user of the app using SQL injection to gain unauthorized access to the apps server springs to mind. I'm not well versed in what all the possible scenarios are as I'm relatively new to Application security. Is input validation not necessary here?

Comment: An example of what I'm attempting would be a regex such as:
NSString *pattern = @"^(?:\\n+|\\w+)$";

However this won't suffice as most good passwords will consist of more than just alphanumeric characters.

Comment: SQL injection protection should be done on the server.

Comment: Is any input validation needed on the client application?

Comment: Just found this. Asks it better than I did.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045188/is-password-input-sanitization-required?rq=1

Thanks all, apologies about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take what ever the user entered and hash it, then use the hash as the password. That way the user has no control over the exact password.

Better yet use [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), it is designed to create derived keys from a password.